# Dynamically Adding Class of Controls

Tags: c#, winforms

I am having trouble with dynamically adding a class of controls that should when working look like this:

[image]

When a new one is added it should appear in the left panel under the toolstrip.
So far I am having trouble making them appear (The one in the middle is just the design I made).

[image]

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Problem Occurs Here
        EquationBox[] EquationBoxArray = new EquationBox[12];
        for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
        {
            EquationBoxArray[x] = new EquationBox();
            ActiveForm.Controls.Add(EquationBoxArray[x].mainPanel);
            ActiveForm.Controls.Add(EquationBoxArray[x].colorPanel);
        }
    }

    private void add_line_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Add Line
    {

    }

    private void clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Clear Lines
    {

    }
}

public class EquationBox
{        
    public Panel colorPanel = new Panel();
    public Panel mainPanel = new Panel();
    public TextBox equationBox = new TextBox();
    public CheckBox isVisibleBox = new CheckBox();

    public EquationBox()
    {
        mainPanel.Size = new Size(200, 72);
        colorPanel.Size = new Size(33, 72);
        mainPanel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        colorPanel.Location = new Point(50, 50);

        colorPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs here:

```
    //Problem Occurs Here
    EquationBox[] EquationBoxArray = new EquationBox[12];
    for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
    {
        EquationBoxArray[x] = new EquationBox();
        ActiveForm.Controls.Add(EquationBoxArray[x].mainPanel);
        ActiveForm.Controls.Add(EquationBoxArray[x].colorPanel);
    }
```

When I run it, it return with:

`Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

And even before that started happening, the EqautionBox wouldn't appear.

Thanks in advance, this is really troubling me.

For the constructor of EquationBox:

```
public EquationBox()
{
    mainPanel.Size = new Size(200, 72);
    colorPanel.Size = new Size(33, 72);
    mainPanel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
    colorPanel.Location = new Point(50, 50);

    colorPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: What does the constructor for EquationBox look like?

Comment: you mean this?



` public EquationBox()
    {
        mainPanel.Size = new Size(200, 72);
        colorPanel.Size = new Size(33, 72);
        mainPanel.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        colorPanel.Location = new Point(50, 50);

        colorPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }`

Comment: Try `User Controls`:  Right click your project, select Add..., User Control..., Name the User Control and click OK.  Drag and Drop the TextBox, CheckBox, etc. on to the User Control.   Now you can instantiate it and add it to the form.

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple threads anywhere in your application? How does `Form1` get instantiated?

Comment: Thank you @SteveWellens that makes it work easier. But I still am having trouble with threads.

Comment: @NicholasRamsay - If you have multiple threads accessing GUI elements, you'll need to become familiar with `Control.Invoke`.   It may seem complicated at first but it is the only way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your control appeared, but mainPanel is overlap colorPanel and you can't see mainPanel (same BG color as your form), so swap which added first solved

```
EquationBox[] EquationBoxArray = new EquationBox[12];
for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++)
{
    EquationBoxArray[x] = new EquationBox();
    this.Controls.Add(EquationBoxArray[x].colorPanel);
    this.Controls.Add(EquationBoxArray[x].mainPanel);
}
```

I am using `this.Controls`, not sure about the `ActiveForm.Controls` part, maybe on constructing, your `Form1` is not the active one, so error occured.

Ps: I suggest add colorPanel to mainPanel, and only add mainPanel to Form. And UserControl is a good solution here as Steve Wellens said.

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues with `EquationBox` the TextBox and CheckBox are not in the panel.  It would be easier to make it a [UserControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302342.aspx).

Then to do the positioning use a [FlowLayoutPanel.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel(v=vs.110).aspx)